# Sage Pay Select Payment Method

Tags: opencart, opayo

I'm using a test sagepay account through opencarts sagepay integration - everything seems fine until i get to sagepay's payment page.

There is no payment methods being offered even though visa and mastercard are displayed as payment methods in the admin panel. Surely it can't be anything wrong on my part?

[image: sage pay payment page]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the card types aren't associated with the MerchantID that is being used for the transaction, for that currency/accounttype combination.

If you are sure that you are sending transactions with AccountType=E, you have an ecommerce MID on that vendor account and the currency you are using is also associated with that ecom MID, then give Sage Pay a call - they can make sure the vendor account is properly configured at their side.